# HTML Email BlackBerry Conditional Styling

Tags: html, css, blackberry, media-queries, html-email

I am wondering if there is a way to use conditional targeting for a blackberry specifically a BB running BB OS7 or Z10 (i might be off here i am not a BB user). We just started doing Responsive emails and BB's are being a pain. They look perfect on iOS and Android but if i make an edit to fix the BB it throws off iOS and Android. Any idea of how i can "add space" to spots only on a BB through media queries or conditional styling?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is. There may however be alternative ways to prevent the issue happening in the first place. Post your code and we can (hopefully) suggest a different way to do whatever is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks John -  But just got word from the agency it wasn't a big deal, after we ran a report that said that we had 4 opens on a blackberry out of 415k emails pushed.

Comment: No worries. I don't usually stress too much on BB, just like old Lotus Notes. In my opinion, that 0.1% need to upgrade...